# Access to class methods from servlet

Tags: java, servlets, methods, call

I want to call a method from servlet. I have below class:

```
public class course {

public ResultSet course_in_dept(String dept_name) {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        String Query = "select course_id , title from course where dept_name=?";
        PreparedStatement pst = Database.dbConnect().prepareStatement(Query);
        pst.setString(1, dept_name);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        return rs;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Database.error = 1;
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

And now I want to call `course_in_dept` method from this class in `doPost` method of my servlet. Now how I can handle it?

Comment: Get an instance of type `course` and use it.

Comment: You should not return a `ResultSet`, read from it then close it

Comment: That's not very useful. Tell us which error and why.

Comment: Also FYI this is not a class method (a.k.a. static method), but an instance method

Comment: Please consider capitalizing your classes and using proper naming conventions for your methods and variables for readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try create instance and call it like:

```
course courseResult = new course();
ResultSet resultSet = courseResult.course_in_dept("Engineering");
```